# How to delete bootstrap sessionstorage items when user redirects or sign out from that page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation where user creates some bootstrap sessionstorage items for example selected tab index, what should we do to delete those sessionstorage items when he/she go away from that page using JavaScript. Please help me with clear code to pass this situation. Is there any page cycle we can access when user gets redirected from current page. I really appreciate your responses. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

**You can completely clear sessionStorage using**

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```